# Finding a sender without passing it as a parameter in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using an API that is used with RFID terminals. When any of the terminals fires an event, the API take care of it and passes appropriate parameter to the procedure:

```
For i = 0 to NumberOfTerminals - 1
    myTerminals(i).ID = i
    myTerminals(i).API.Connect()
    AddHandler myTerminals(i).API.OnRFID, AddressOf OnRFIDSub
End For

Private Sub OnConnectSub(ByVal RFID As String, ByVal EventTime As String)
    MsgBox(RFID & " : " & EventTime)
End Sub
```

The problem is that when event is fired, there is no `sender` or `e` attribute passed from the API. Is there a way to know which terminal fired the event without the `sender` object?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I believe you don't need `c#` tag for this question. `vb.net` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vb syntax escapes me, but it seems you can add a a different handler to each terminal. So add a handler to terminal `i` that passes it's terminal(i) to the function as sender.

The easiest way to achieve this would probably be lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2):

to expand on nvoigts answer

```
For i = 0 to NumberOfTerminals - 1
    myTerminals(i).ID = i
    myTerminals(i).API.Connect()
    'copy the id as there are problems with closing over iteration variables.
    dim id as integer = i
    'Lamda sub to close over id
    AddHandler myTerminals(i).API.OnRFID, _
        Sub(ByVal RFID As String, ByVal EventTime As String) _ 
            OnRFIDSub(RFID,EventTime,id) 
End For

Private Sub OnConnectSub(ByVal RFID As String, ByVal EventTime As String, 
                         ByVal Sender as Integer) 'Sender now contains the terminal ID
    MsgBox(RFID & " : " & EventTime)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly! Thank you (and nvoigts) for the solution.